# az appconfig kv list --key filter not working for * wildcard

Tags: azure, azure-keyvault, azure-cli

I have a KeyValue pair in azure appConfiguration

[image: keyValuePair]

and when I run the following command, it does not work. however another version of it is working

```
    //works
    az appconfig kv list -n app-config-dev --key 'my*'
    //does not work
    az appconfig kv list -n app-config-dev --key '*Key'
```

[image]

documentation says this
[image]

what am I doing wrong

Comment: it probably only supports prefix ?

Comment: you coud probably work around that using jmespath ? `az appconfig kv list -n cockpit-app-config-dev --query "[?ends_with(key, 'key')]"`

Comment: so weird.. it only showed 3 keys out of 9. but when I used --all, then it returned all 9.

az appconfig kv list -n app-config-dev --query "[?ends_with(key, 'Key')]" --all

Comment: thanks @Thomas, this will work for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure but I'm guessing the `--key` argument only supports prefix.
You could use jmespath to work around that:

```
az appconfig kv list -n cockpit-app-config-dev --query "[?ends_with(key, 'key')]" --all
```

Note:

The query filter is applied on the results of the command so you need to get `--all` secrets then the query is applied (see [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/query-azure-cli))